# syntax error: 'constant' while using flex

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation, flex-lexer, lex

Well topic speak for himself, here example of a code(lex file before compilation):

```
%{

#include<stdio.h>
int Upperc=0;
int Lowerc=0;
%}

%%
[A-Z] {printf("Upperccase\t");Upperc++;}
[a-z] {printf("Lowerccase\t");Lowerc++;}
%%



main()
{
printf("Enter a string\n");
yylex();

printf("Upperccase=%d and Lowerccase=%d",Upperc,Lowerc);
}
```

for some reason when trying to run at vs13, I'm always getting  `syntax error: 'constant'` , there is no line or any information about there error except this,
please help me understand what is wrong, thanks!

Comment: Runs fine for me (flex 2.5.35, Ubuntu).

Comment: Works fine for me, too, with flex 2.5.37 / gcc 4.8.5.  Make sure you're not trying to compile the Flex input as if it were C source.

Comment: I had a wrong information written, it was with vs13, after installed vs10 it was fixed.... (I dont know if that was the issue or what..)

Comment: Surely you mean when trying to *compile*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it seems after 5 hours of not understanding the problem ( and 20 minutes after posted here, that the issue was with VS13 ,after installing VS10 everything was fixed...
Thank you all!